# how can i get rid of these errors when trying to start a Django project?

Tags: django

I am trying to start a django project using the `django-admin startproject` but it keeps bringing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\startproject.py", line 20, in handle
    super().handle('project', project_name, target, **options)
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\templates.py", line 117, in handle
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 16, in setup
    from django.urls import set_script_prefix
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import (
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .exceptions import NoReverseMatch, Resolver404
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\exceptions.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.http import Http404
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\http\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.http.response import (
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from django.core.serializers.base import SerializerDoesNotExist
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.db.models.aggregates import *  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\aggregates.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.db.models.expressions import Case, Func, Star, When
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\expressions.py", line 486, in <module>
    class TemporalSubtraction(CombinedExpression):
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\expressions.py", line 487, in TemporalSubtraction
    output_field = fields.DurationField()
  File "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 155, in __init__
    if isinstance(choices, collections.Iterator):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterator'
```

How can i fix this? At first, I created a virtual environment where I installed django and created a project using the same command and I did not get the error, but when I tried to run the `python manage.py runserver` command, I got this error:

```
(venv) C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\DEV\trydjango\venv>python manage.py runserver
C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\\DEV\\trydjango\\venv\\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

[image: after running startproject command]
[image: after running the command this window pops up then nothing]

Comment: Does django installed successfully in `virtualenv`,  was you able to check it's version through `django-admin --version` or not?

Comment: The first issue seems to be caused because you're using the global python. Maybe your packages are missing there? The second one seems like your not in the right folder. When executing `python manage.py runserver` you should be in the folder where the `manage.py` file is. According to your traceback, you're in the `venv` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should be in the project's root folder in order to run the command `python manage.py runserver`

According to your error, you are somewhere in `venv` folder.

You should be in the **trydjango** folder (according to the screenshots) and then run the above command.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks,i started all over again using your solution so now when i run django-admin this happpens:

Comment: (venv) C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\DEV\trydjango\pro2>django-admin startproject firewill

(venv) C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\DEV\trydjango\pro2>cd firewill
The system cannot find the path specified.

(venv) C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\DEV\trydjango\pro2>python manage.py runserver
C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\\DEV\\trydjango\\pro2\\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory, so the django-admin startproject is not creating a project folder which contains the manage.py file

Comment: Please attach the snapshot of the error you are getting.. it will be easier for us to solve then.. by snapshot i mean screenshot.

Comment: i dont know how to attach a screenshot on my comment but when i run the startproject command another  cmd window pops up written "C:\Users\GAbraham.AECIGROUP\DEV\trydjango\venv\Scripts\gdjango-admin.exe" which closes after a few seconds but nothing happens after that

Comment: Attach screenshot to your question, not comment..

Comment: i have attached the screenshots

Comment: See.. you should be in the folder trydjango and then run the runserver command.

Comment: Read my answer.. I've esited it based on the question update

Comment: its still not working, i guess there must be something wrong with my system because i am facing the same problems when i run flutter commands on cmd

Comment: Yes, might be your system is causing the problem